# How can I call a Typescript generic method with a dynamically determined generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics

I get this error with the code below:
'realType' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof realType'?(

```
class Quux{};
class Foo extends Quux{};
class Bar extends Quux{};

const quuxBundle: Record<string, typeof Quux> = {
  "Foo": Foo,
  "Bar": Bar
};  

function lookupQuuxType(typeName: string): typeof Quux | undefined {
  return quuxBundle[typeName];
}
function fetchQuux<T extends Quux() {
  const result = {} as T;
  console.log('result', typeof result);
  return result;
}

const realType = lookupQuuxType('Foo');
fetchQuux<realType>();
```

Comment: First of all, the code you sent isn't even valid syntax (what is `<T extends Quux() {` supposed to be?), but also Typescript is meant to be a purely compile-time typesystem that has no effect on the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a const as a type, if you want to use the type of your const you should use it in this way `typeof realType`.

Here is your updated code:

```
class Quux{};
class Foo extends Quux{};
class Bar extends Quux{};

const quuxBundle: Record<string, typeof Quux> = {
  "Foo": Foo,
  "Bar": Bar
};  

function lookupQuuxType(typeName: string): typeof Quux | undefined {
  return quuxBundle[typeName];
}
function fetchQuux<T extends Quux>() {
  const result = {} as T;
  console.log('result', typeof result);
  return result;
}

const realType = lookupQuuxType('Foo');
fetchQuux<typeof realType>();
```

Comment: Merely adding 'typeof' doesn't make it work.